# Maximum Sum BST in a Binary Tree

Tags: java, time-limit-exceeded, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I was trying to find the [Maximum sum BST of a binary tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-sum-bst-in-binary-tree/) on LeetCode. While the Java code I have come up with, mostly seems right and is able to pass 55 out of the given 59 test cases too, the error of 'Time Limit Exceeded' comes up.

Is there anything I can change, in the same given code, that would optimize it and/or get it accepted?

---

## problem statement

> ### 1373. Maximum Sum BST in Binary Tree
>
> Given a binary tree root, return the maximum sum of all keys of any sub-tree which is also a Binary Search Tree (BST).
>
> Assume a BST is defined as follows:
>
> - The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys less than the node's key.
> - The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than the node's key.
> - Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.
>
> ### example
>
> Input: root = [1,4,3,2,4,2,5,null,null,null,null,null,null,4,6]
> Output: 20
> Explanation: Maximum sum in a valid Binary search tree is obtained in root node with key equal to 3.
>
> Constraints:
> The number of nodes in the tree is in the range [1, 4 * 10⁴].
> -4 * 1e⁴ <= Node.val <= 4 * 1e⁴

---

The contest calls `Solution.maxSumBST()`

```
class Solution {

    int maxSum = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    TreeNode ansNode = new TreeNode();


    private boolean isBST(TreeNode root, int minVal, int maxVal) {        //To check if a tree is a BST

        if (root==null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (root.val>=maxVal || root.val<=minVal) {
            return false;
        }

        return (isBST(root.left, minVal, root.val) && isBST(root.right, root.val, maxVal));
    }


    private void rootFinder(TreeNode root) {                     //Helper function to find the root of the required BST
        
        if (root==null) {
            return;
        }

        rootFinder(root.left);


        if (isBST(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {

            int currSum = sumFinder(root);
            if (currSum > maxSum) {
                maxSum = currSum;
                ansNode = root;
            }
            sum = 0;
        }

        rootFinder(root.right);
    }


    public int maxSumBST(TreeNode root) {

        rootFinder(root);
        return maxSum;
    }


    private int sumFinder (TreeNode root) {          //To find the sum of all the nodes of a tree

        if (root==null) {
            return 0;
        }

        sumFinder(root.left);
        sum = sum + root.val;
        sumFinder(root.right);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: @greybeard, the contest calls maxSumBST(), and evaluates the returned integer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything I can change, in the same given code, that would optimize it and/or get it accepted?

Your “Time Limit Exceeded” question is basically asking “when is this code slow?”
We tend to think of binary trees as “fast”, especially if it’s a **balanced** binary search tree.
Your code does well on such trees.

We also know that sometimes it is “slow”.
When is that?
Must be when (part of) the input is not a well formed BST.

Now play the role of adversary.
You’re dreaming up horrible inputs to feed this code.
What should they look like?

First of all, “big”.
And also, “unbalanced” / “not well formed”.

Your code’s current goal is to declare “not a BST!” as soon as possible, if indeed it’s not a BST.
There are left and right conditions to verify, and either could let us bail early.
The current code deterministically investigates the left subtree in its entirety before considering the right.
Upon visiting a node it is free to flip a coin and investigate one or the other first.

Let’s maintain a global visits counter.
When even, we get the current behavior.
When odd, investigate right first, then left.

The idea is that when presented with a giant, highly unbalanced subtree which is not even a BST, we won’t be lured deep into that briar patch.

Now, an adversary who knows or guesses our algorithm may still be able to manipulate it.
A source of true random numbers allows to defeat such an adversary.
We call this a stochastic algorithm.

---

Actually, a more principled approach would be
to track which `level` we're currently investigating,
and explore Left or Right based on the level's low bit.

With only twice as many possible values as there are nodes,
the adversary is limited when trying to come up with
a valid labeling for some annoyingly unbalanced tree.

---

Let N be number of input nodes,
and M <= N is number of nodes that are in well-formed BSTs.

The best we can do is O(M) time complexity,
since we must evaluate the inequalities for M nodes.
When M is "most" of the nodes,
that is, when M is O(N),
then the OP code is performant,
having O(N) and therefore O(M) complexity.

When M << N, the OP code may fail to complete in O(M) time,
as it spends "too long" investigating left subtrees.

Comment: `Your code does well on [balanced BST]s` I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond method naming and a comment stating what the signature `boolean isBST(TreeNode root,…)` suggest, the code gives no indication what it is there for, *what* the methods *need to* and *do accomplish* and *how*:

Document your code. In the code.
With Java, the conventional mechanism is providing [doc comments](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide).
`maxSum` and `sum` deserve a comment about the extreme values possible.

`ansNode` is not used. (LeetCode's problem title *Maximum Sum BST …* is delusory; compare to *Maximum BST Sum …*.)

Code indentation is consistent.
Use of white space isn't quite: there is a double blank line in `rootFinder()`;
sometimes there are spaces around comparison operators, sometimes not; there is *one* block statement starting with a blank line. (I prefer to go easier on vertical space: just one blank line between "peer" items such as methods, no blank line following an opening brace.)

In comparisons, especially in multiple related ones, I prefer "expressions arranged in ascending order":
`if (root.val <= minVal || maxVal <= root.val) // no BST`
(actually, I prefer

```
        return root == null
               || minVal < root.val && root.val < maxVal
                  && isBST(root.left, minVal, root.val)
                  && isBST(root.right, root.val, maxVal);
```

) - note this already suffers the "susceptibility" [J_H points out](/a/289525/93149) as a "point of attack".

`sum += root.val;` reads *add to sum* more immediately than `sum = sum + …`.

`Helper function` does not add useful information to a private method member; +it rubs me the wrong way with a `void` method.

There is an untoward interdependency between `rootFinder()` setting `sum` to zero and `sumFinder()` manipulating it. "Split handling" wasn't a problem if the latter was named `accumulator()` or `updater()`:
The problem is starting a sum with zero is a *sumFinder*'s responsibility. A variable "global" to sumFinder may just not be the way to communicate the running total.

---

regarding TLE:
Imagine a tree with every `right` `null`, the root's `val` 9999 and each `left`'s `val` "one smaller" stopping at -9999:
How many times does your code visit "node 42"?

---

Imagine an instance method like this:

```
/** Handles both subtrees recursively, updating <code>maxSum</code> as appropriate.
 * @returns the sum of all node's <code>val</code>s if this subtree is a BST.
 * @…
 */
int sumIfBST(TreeNode root)
```

How could you handle *not a BST*? How could you handle *not well-formed*?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is inefficient; there is no need to run a linear check on each subtree to determine whether or not it is a binary search tree. Instead, you can use a single linear (in the number of nodes) DFS and collect information about each subtree as you go.

In particular, for each subtree, find the minimum and maximum key of any node contained within, the sum of all nodes, and whether it is a BST. These can all be calculated from the information on the subtrees of its two children in constant time. We can use a `record` to store these values, along with an additional field for the largest sum of keys in a subtree that is a BST that is contained within the current subtree. The final answer can be directly retrieved from this field at the root.

```java
class Solution {
    record SubtreeInfo(int maxBstSum, int sum, int minVal, int maxVal, boolean isBst){}
    public int maxSumBST(TreeNode root) {
        return solve(root).maxBstSum;
    }
    private SubtreeInfo solve(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) return new SubtreeInfo(0, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, true);
        SubtreeInfo leftInfo = solve(node.left), rightInfo = solve(node.right);
        int currMaxSum = Math.max(leftInfo.maxBstSum, rightInfo.maxBstSum), 
            currSum = node.val + leftInfo.sum + rightInfo.sum;
        boolean currIsBst = leftInfo.isBst && rightInfo.isBst && leftInfo.maxVal < node.val && rightInfo.minVal > node.val;
        if (currIsBst) currMaxSum = Math.max(currMaxSum, currSum);
        return new SubtreeInfo(currMaxSum, currSum, Math.min(node.val, Math.min(leftInfo.minVal, rightInfo.minVal)),
            Math.max(node.val, Math.max(leftInfo.maxVal, rightInfo.maxVal)), currIsBst);
    }
}
```